# How to pass the sender parameter to the system.timers.timer

Tags: c#, .net

How do you pass the sender parameter to the `system.timers.timer` in .NET?

```
timer1[timer] = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
timer1[timer].AutoReset = true;
timer1[timer].Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(datatransferEvent);
timer1[timer].Start();
GC.KeepAlive(timer1[timer]);


private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        serverreconnected.Stop();
        reconnect(_opcServer);
    }
    finally
    {
        serverreconnected.Start();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
System.Threading.Timer timer1;
timer1= new System.Threading.Timer(databaseTrensfer, row, dueTime, interval);

public void databaseTrensfer(object row)
{
    DataRow rowE = (DataRow)row;
}
```

Row pass to the parameter to the function `databaseTrensfer()`

I want to pass the the sender parameter to the event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh? That's not your job. The timer instance fires the event. sender normally contains the firing instance, but you can't always rely on that.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The sender parameter will be filled automatically with the sending timer when the event will be raised.

Comment: i want to pass the parameter to like threading pass the object or window.timer pass the tag property

Comment: Show us an example of what you would like, because you are not explaining well.

Answer (score 12):

I like zabulus's method, but there is an alternative.  Create your own Timer class that inherits from System.Timers.Timer and it can hold anything you want.  I chose to do the basic object Tag property so it can be reused in other projects.

```
public class MyTimer : System.Timers.Timer
{
    public MyTimer(double interval)
        : base(interval)
    {
    }

    public object Tag { get; set; }
}

MyTimer timer;
void test(object sender)
{
    timer = new MyTimer(1);
    timer.Tag = sender;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
}

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer timer = (MyTimer)sender;
    object tag = timer.Tag;
    // do whatever you want with tag
}
```

Then call `test(with whatever value you want to pass)`.

Comment: Voting for your answer this was my first suggestion, but I had little mistaken in classes: System.Threading.Timer is sealed unlike the System.Timers.Timer.

Comment: Hello,how do I convert tag object into a string ?

Comment: @k4lls either `timer.Tag.ToString()` or `(string)timer.Tag`

Comment: This is great! I think it could be further improved by changing to a generic `MyTimer<T>` and then using `public T Tag {get;set;}` property so you don't need to type cast the object.

Answer (score 2):

create aggregation class that holds your row.

```
class RowHolderEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DataRow row;
    public RowHolderEventArgs(DataRow row)
    {
        this.row = row;
    }
};
public delegate void RowHolderEvent(object sender, RowHolderEventArgs e);
class RowHolder
{
    public event RowHolderEvent Elapsed;
    DataRow row;
    public RowHolder(DataRow row, Timer timer)
    {
        this.row = row;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Elapsed != null)
        {
            Elapsed(sender, new RowHolderEventArgs(row));
        }
    }
}
```

using

```
timer1[timer] = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
rowHolder[timer] = new RowHolder(timer1[timer],row[timer]);
rowHolder.Elapsed+=new RowHolderEvent(databaseTrensfer)

public void databaseTrensfer(object sender, HolderEventArgs e)
{
 DataRow rowE = (DataRow)e.row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
static Timer timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var row = default(DataRow); // Some row
    timer = new Timer(30000);
    timer.Elapsed += (_, __) => databaseTrensfer(row);
}

static void databaseTrensfer(DataRow row)
{
    // Do something with 'row'
}
```