# if specific time passed show messagebox in C#

Tags: c#, timer, messagebox, stopwatch

so, i want this: if specific time passed (for example 9 hours) from loading form, than i want to show messagebox said "9 hours passed". my code is this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stopWatch.Start();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sec = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
        double min = sec / 60;
        double hour = min / 60;
        if (hour == 9.00D)
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("passed: " + hour.ToString("0.00"));
        }
    }
}
```

and the problem is that i don't know where to write this part of code:

```
if (hour == 9.00D)
        {
            stopWatch.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("passed: " + hour.ToString("0.00"));
        }
```

so, where i write this code?  if you have better way of doing this, please show me.

Comment: You write the code when the Timer event happens.  Read the documentation on the Timer class its pretty self explainitory.

Comment: you should read how to use timer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094008/how-to-use-timer-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you want the popup to show even if the button was not clicked? Or do you want it to show only once the button was clicked?

Comment: this is also helpful http://csharpdevelopertool.blogspot.ie/2012/02/make-countdown-timer-in-cnet.html

Comment: if the button was not clicked too.

Comment: I hope you didn't wait 9 hours to see if this worked!

Comment: @Ramhound you mean Tick event? it doesn't work either. or I'm doing something wrong. why don't you give me some code?

Comment: @weston of course not, i waited 0.001 hour.

Comment: @samuraisxmali - What doesn't work exactly. You don't even implement the `Tick` event nor have a `Timer` object currently in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What people are not appreciating is that it is very unlikely that the `double hours` will be exactly 9.00! Why not just ask your timer to fire once, after the time you want, 9 hours.

```
Timer timer;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(9).TotalMilliseconds;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show("9 hours passed");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using a Timer as outlined by the others, you can directly use the TotalHours() property of the TimeSpan returned by Stopwatch.Elapsed:

```
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        if (ts.TotalHours >= 9)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("passed: " + ts.TotalHours.ToString("0.00"));
        }
```

Comment: You'd put that in the Tick() event in place of the previous code that was manually calculating "sec", "min" and "hour".  *Assuming you didn't use the code from weston that set the Interval() to the entire desired time duration!  =)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do a specific task after a specific period of time System.Forms.Timer should be used (in case of windows forms). You can use its Elapsed event and in that you can implement your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Timer instead. [Example from here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f/)

```
Timer timer;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // when timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
    timer.Interval = (1000) * (10);             // Timer will tick every 10 seconds
    timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
    timer.Start();                              // Start the timer
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double sec = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
    double min = sec / 60;
    double hour = min / 60;
    if (hour == 9.00D)
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show("passed: " + hour.ToString("0.00"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timer](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer):

> Timer regularly invokes code. Every several seconds or minutes, it
>   executes a method. This is useful for monitoring the health of an
>   important program, as with diagnostics. The System.Timers namespace
>   proves useful.

see this:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            stopWatch.Start();
            tm.Interval = 1000;
            tm.Enabled = true; 
            tm.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);
            tm.Start();
        }

        void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double sec = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
            double min = sec / 60;
            double hour = min / 60;
            if (hour == 9.00D)
            {
                stopWatch.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("passed: " + hour.ToString("0.00"));
            }
        }
     }
```