# I need to create a timer based application?

Tags: c#, timer

I need to create a application which must have a timer control;
the timer must automatically initialize when each form is called, when the time reach 3 seconds means it must load the another form.

I have tried this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    if (timer1.Interval = 3000)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Times up");
        form2 i=new form2();
        form2.show();
    }
}
```

but I cant get the correct result....

Comment: Your concept of timer is wrong. See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094008/how-to-use-timer-in-c-sharp

Comment: found it guys  Timer timer;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Interval = 3000;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Times up");
            Form2 i = new Form2();
            i.Show();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Timers in C# work by firing events periodically. You need to attach an event handler which responds to the timer event. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a straightforward example (code snippet reproduced below).

```
public Timer aTimer;

public static void Main()
{
    // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

// Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
// raised. 
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

initialize and enable your timer and attach an event handler to Tick event.

```
Timer timer;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Times up");
    Form2 i = new Form2();
    i.Show();
}
```

Comment: @Ben yeah thanks.I just copied the code in the question and forgot to change it

Comment: @Selman22 i need help i m facing these errors                Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()' C:\Documents and Settings\AnbuRaj\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 23 13 WindowsFormsApplication1
Error 2 The name 'timer_Tick' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\AnbuRaj\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 31 27 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: @Anburaj an Object reference is set up as Selman22 has done in the `timer_tick` method. `i` is an object reference of `Form2`

Comment: Dude thats not the problem i found it i add this  timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick); the errors disappear thanks man i own u one...:)

Comment: also, try to keep your object references similar to your object names. So instead of `i` perhaps use `Form2 form = new Form2;`. The variable `i` is used more commonly as a 'sentinel varaible'