# auto save file which is already saved C# using timer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, richtextbox, invoke, autosave

the code i have mention below shows my auto save function.where should i call the this method  to auto save my text while typing after every 5 seconds.please explain me

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            tmr.Interval = 5000;

            tmr.Start();
            File_Save_MenuItem_Click(sender,e);

            tmr.Stop();

        }
```

Comment: Try read [this post, how to use C# timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094008/how-to-use-timer-in-c-sharp), it might help you understand how timer works. But in your case it is better not to use auto reset timer and stop it before save and start it after save ended.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets think about this like a human..   If I was writing a book on a piece of paper and you wanted to make sure you had a backup of what I was doing, you'd probably photo copy the page as I completed it.  You wouldnt do it if I hadnt changed anything.

From a computer point of view you've said you want to save your file every 5 seconds (thats really often!!) however, you havent really explained how you started.

Im going to assume you made like a notepad app - in your notepad app, theres a textbox your file is in, all you need to do is have a timer that says after 5 seconds, stop timer, and save file .. thats it.  Then in the onchange of the textbox, if timer is disabled, start timer.

edit:

In your code above you've made a timer event, but then inside that you're making the timer, not setting anything to happen when the time is up.. so Im guessing this code never happens

Comment: i have a richtext box which .i want to save the text every 5 seconds while i type.what i have done is .i added a timer.then added this implementation  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            tmr.Interval = 500;

            tmr.Start();
            File_Save_MenuItem_Click(sender,e);
          
            tmr.Stop();
            
        }
where do i have to invoke it to make it work.

Comment: As above - if you have timer1 set to 5000 on your form, you dont need "tmr" its not doing anything.. then in the onchange - in the case of richtextbox "Modifiedchanged"

Comment: i have implemented only this function.what do i have to do to call my auto save function.can u please provide code on how to do it?