# .NET System.Timers.Timer How to pass parameters to a delegate function?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to call a function on a set timer. Currently I'm using the system.timers.timer sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx

```
iaTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(60000)
'Hook up the Elapsed event for the time
AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, (AddressOf OnTimedEvent)
aTimer.Enabled = True

'The event handler for the Timer.Elapsed event.  
Public Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs, ByVal companies() As companyAccount)
    timermain(companies)
End Sub
```

I do not know how to pass parameters to the delegate. The array companies() is an array of companyAccount objects which are basically structs.  I need these parameters to be fed to the timermain function. Elsewhere in the code I have a delegate that accepts parameters to update textboxes, So this should be possible.

I think this question is similar.  [How to pass the sender parameter to the system.timers.timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368399/how-to-pass-the-the-sender-parameter-to-the-system-timers-timer)

Comment: Look up "lambda expression" in your favorite VB.NET language book or Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the `Timer.Elapsed` event signature (or generally change the signature of events) to pass additional parameters. Instead, you should declare your `companies` variable in a scope that will be accessible to the event handler.

You can do this by making it class-level, if all this code is in the same class.

```
Class SomeClass
    Private companies() As CompanyAccount

    Sub SetupTimer()
        iaTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(60000)
        ' Hook up the Elapsed event for the time
        AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, (AddressOf OnTimedEvent)
        aTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    ' The event handler for the Timer.Elapsed event.  
    Public Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
        timermain(companies)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You may also be able to use a lambda expression:

```
Dim companies() As CompanyAccount
companies = ...
iaTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(60000)
AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, Sub(sender, e) timermain(companies)
aTimer.Enabled = True
```